# React Native : BLE, Discover & Broadcast (advertise data)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm very new to BLE APIs and capabilities. I want to achieve a "simple" thing. Let's say I'm developing the APP-X. I want to be able to scan other phone around me, with APP-X installed (exactly like this app here https://www.tracetogether.gov.sg/ ). I want to scan and filter the wanted devices via a "simple" metadata (advertising data ? specific for my app) within the signal emitted by the concerned phones. I'm stuck because Idk how to "emit" (broadcast) that custom signal.

Can you please help me find a way to do this in RN ?

I have already check those libs:

- https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx : but they have noticed that the lib does not support `communicating between phones using BLE (Peripheral support)`
- https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager : Didn't see any Advertising API there

Many thanks

Answer (score -2):

I'm currently using React Native Ble PLX !
And indeed, they don't support ble peripheral.

In the react native ble plx, i found an issue when a developper posted a link to a library that can do advertising :

https://github.com/petrbela/react-native-peripheral
But it seems Android not supported ?

Another do an advertising :
https://github.com/himelbrand/react-native-ble-peripheral#readme

But i don't know if it's the best way to achieve what you want.